# How to Enable Battery Optimizations for App

Tags: android, android-intent, battery

I have an app that allows to disable battery optimizations by calling:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
this.startActivity(intent);
```

But how can the user enable battery optimizations again from "within" the app?

When the optimizations are ignored already, the menu won't show up.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
var intent = Intent();
intent.action = Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
intent.data = Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName())
startActivityForResult(intent, IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_REQUEST);
```